# React-speech-recognition using with React-media-recorder in React(Next.js) does not work on Android mobile

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, web-mediarecorder

I would like to use "[react-speech-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition?activeTab=readme)" and "[react-media-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder)" in my React/Next.js App implementation to perform speech recognition and voice recording at the same time.
The speech recognition is outputting text.

Implementing only react-speech-recognition,
implementation of only react-media-recorder both worked fine on Android chrome.

Since I want to be able to record at the same time as speech recognition, we have made it so that the recording is controlled by triggering the on/off toggle of speech recognition.

It works as desired on chrome on PC, but on the android device, the recording is working, but the voice recognition is not executing as desired and the text is not output and the app is not working properly.

Since the microphone is supposed to be used for voice recognition and voice recording at the same time, could this be the problem?

I have looked into this but have not been able to solve the problem, so I am posting it here.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SpeechRecognition, {
  useSpeechRecognition,
} from 'react-speech-recognition';


const WebSpeechAPI = ({ checkAnswer }) => {
  const {
    transcript,
    finalTranscript,
    listening,
    resetTranscript,
    browserSupportsSpeechRecognition,
    isMicrophoneAvailable,
  } = useSpeechRecognition();

  const [isListening, setIsListing] = useState(false);

  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';
  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition && !isServer) {
    return <div>your browser does not support</div>;
  }

  const handleSwitch = () => {
    if (!isListening) {
      SpeechRecognition.startListening({ language: 'ja' });
    } else {
      SpeechRecognition.stopListening();
    }
    setIsListing(!isListening);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ fontSize: '2rem' }}>マイク: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => SpeechRecognition.startListening({ language: 'ja' })}
        className="micb"
        style={{ padding: '1em', marginRight: '10px' }}
      >
        Start
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}
        className="micb"
        style={{ padding: '1em', marginRight: '10px' }}
      >
        Stop
      </button>
      <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
      <form>
        <p>{isMicrophoneAvailable}</p>
        <p>{transcript}</p>
        <p>{finalTranscript}</p>
      </form>
      <ReactMediaRecorder listening={listening} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default WebSpeechAPI;
```

```
import { useReactMediaRecorder } from 'react-media-recorder';

export function ReactMediaRecorder({ listening }) {
  const [voice, setVoice] = useState('');

  // Voice acquisition part
  const { startRecording, stopRecording, mediaBlobUrl, audio, status } =
    useReactMediaRecorder({
      video: false,
      audio: true,
      echoCancellation: true,
    });


  useEffect(() => {
    listening ? startRecording() : stopRecording();
  }, [listening]);

  return (
    <>
      <h4>react-media-recorder</h4>
      <div>
        <div></div>
        <div style={{ height: '38px' }}>
          <audio src={mediaBlobUrl} controls></audio>
          <a download href={mediaBlobUrl}>
            Download
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried the following...

Do not use voice recognition as the trigger for voice recording,
I also tried to execute voice recognition and voice recording at the same time with different buttons, but both were not executed at the same time on Android (they were executed on PC browser).